# Interpretation of this calibration curve on prediction models

Tags: r, predictive-models, survival, interpretation, calibration

I have several prediction models that I present in this calibration curve using R with the package "riskRegression".

In this study, the participants are community-dwelling older persons followed up with all-cause mortality as the outcome of interest. Participants' age ranged from 50-100, average age was 63.7 ± 9.7 (SD) years. The participants joined at various stages. Around 13,000 out of the total 36,000 participants lacked censoring information. To address this, we gave the 13,000 participants the outcome of alive with 0 day follow-up.

Here is my interpretation:
The calibration curve appears to be overconfident because its predictions for predicted risk < 37.5% are too low and its predictions for predicted risk > 37.5% are too high relative to actual probability.
This may be due to the lack of censoring information, and also perhaps due to lack of older persons contributing to higher mortality risks.

[image]

My questions:

1. Is my interpretation correct?
2. Why do the lines stopped flat in the middle like that, instead of going upwards? Does this mean there is no one contributing to > 75% observed/predicted risks?
3. This seems to indicate poor calibration of the models. Does this affect the area under the curve (AUC)? Because I measured AUC for these models and the results were very different compared to another similar study with good calibration.

Comment: The interpretation looks right to me but I'm not sure 'overconfident' is the right word. It looks like no one is contributing > about 50% to the observed risks.

Comment: @Great38 Could this be because the dataset is from a pan-European survey and has been studied to underestimate real mortality, therefore the observed risks is low? When I compared annual mortality risk between this dataset and human mortality database and stratify by sex and age groups, the mortality risks in this dataset is lower, especially in females age 70+.

Comment: That sounds possible, though I'm not familiar with the data set. You could look at your data to see what the distribution of observed frequencies is.